# Django: How to make {% extends [file] %} in html file cross platform?

Tags: django

In the login.html there's a line

```
{% extends 'myapp\base.html' %}
```

This does not work on linux but

```
{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}
```

works

How do you make it work cross platform?

Comment: I'm using slash in all of my projects `{% extends 'common/base.html' %}` and this works on Windows (7, 8, 8.1) with Python (3.5, 3.6) and Linux (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{% extends 'myapp/base.html' %}` itself will work cross platform.